# FullCalendar, каким образом добиться выделения диапазона дат при клике?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Кто работал с FullCalendar: (fullcalendar.io)? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать выбор диапазона дат, т.е. при клике на дату выделить ее, при следующем клике на другую дату, выделить все дни между этими датами, включая кликнутые дни. Пример, как должно работать здесь: ( demo.art-creation.ru/range-in-jquery-ui-datepicker/ )

Ссылка на песочницу с календарем(http://codepen.io/Ridik7/pen/XjbNWx)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

.fc-day--background{background-color: red!important;}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // form styles
var calendar = (function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: "auto",
    handleWindowResize: true,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    header: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
    },    

   //selectable: true,

   dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        if(!($(this).hasClass('fc-other-month'))) {
          $(this).toggleClass('fc-day--background');
        } 
    },

  });

})();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать вот так [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/p9q0tyn1/14/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // form styles
var calendar = (function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: "auto",
    handleWindowResize: true,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    header: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
    },    

   //selectable: true,

   dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        if(!($(this).hasClass('fc-other-month'))) {
          $(this).toggleClass('fc-day--background');
        } 
        var dates_selected = $(".fc-day--background");
        if(dates_selected.length == 2 && $(this).hasClass('fc-day--background')) {
          var first_date = dates_selected.first().attr("data-date");
          var last_date = dates_selected.last().attr("data-date");
          $("td.fc-day").each(function(i,el){
            var current_date = $(el).attr("data-date");
            if(current_date > first_date && current_date < last_date){
                $(el).addClass('fc-day--background');
            }
          })
        } else if(dates_selected.length > 2 || (dates_selected.length <= 2 && !$(this).hasClass('fc-day--background'))) {
            $(".fc-day").removeClass('fc-day--background'); 
          if(!($(this).hasClass('fc-other-month'))) {
             $(this).toggleClass('fc-day--background');
          }
        }
    },

  });

})();

});
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо! Ваш код намного короче моего, воспользуюсь Вашим вариантом)